# apt-get fails to, well, apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, debian-lenny

I'm working on a virgin debian 5 image on a VPS.  To be honest, this may not be the brightest VPS provider in the world and I suspect their image isn't perfect.

`apt-get` fails for everything:

```
# apt-get -y install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package gcc
```

There is an `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
```

...which I think is correct.

Now if I use `apt-cache`, I find it:

```
# apt-cache search gcc
libgcc1 - GCC support library
gcc-4.3-base - The GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
```

To be honest, I'm not the world's strongest Debian guy.  Anyone care to speculate where I should start to fix this problem?

Comment: Doesn't apt-get clean && apt-get update help?

Answer (score 2):

Try 'apt-get -y install gcc-4.3-base'

EDIT: To add, unless I'm mistaken, the reason why is because the package is called gcc-4.3-base not just gcc.

Comment: Paul, that worked great. But something is still wrong.  `apt-cache search aptitude` returns nothing.  after apt-getting gcc-4.3-base, I still don't get gcc (ran find / and didn't find a 'gcc').

Comment: You can use apt-cache search $package_name to search

Comment: Dumb question... when was your last `apt-get update`?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all - that turned out to be the issue.  My faith in this VPS vendor is dropping moment by moment...good thing it only cost me $15/year :-)  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: to be fair the VPS provider has done nothing wrong.  To get the latest package list you will always need to do an update, and the error you were suffering from was because you were typing in the wrong package name.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install gcc
```

The package build-essential for lenny ([link](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/build-essential)) should keep you from chasing other missing packages (libs) if you're heading for building sources.